# query results are undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, unit-testing

```
exports.save = function(req, res) {

connection.query('INSERT INTO student_details(name, course, units, grades, gwa) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',[req.body.name,req.body.course,req.body.units,req.body.grades,req.body.gwa], function(err, row) {
    if(err) res.send('Error in query');
    selectOne(row.insertId, function(newRow){
        if(err) res.status(554).send('Error in query');
        if(newRow == null){
            res.send(552, {message: 'Student Details ('+row.insertId+') was not created.'});
        } else{
            res.status(200).send(newRow);
        }
    });
});

}

var selectOne = function(id, callback){

connection.query('SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE id=? LIMIT 1', [id], function(err, rows){
    if(err) return err;
    if(rows.length != 0){
        callback(rows[0]);
    }else{
        callback(null);
    }
});
}
```

I'm having an error performing the query above. It's saying this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now, and my hunch is that it's somewhat related to asynchronous values but I can't figure out how to fix it.

UPDATE:

This is my test file:

```
    var studentdb = require(__dirname + '/../studentdb'),
    student = require(__dirname + '/../student'),
    index = require(__dirname + '/../index'),
    should = require('should-http'),
    assert = require('assert'),
    request = require('supertest');

describe('Student Details', function() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:1337';
    var randomName = student.getRandomName(10);
    var insertedId = 0;
    describe('insert()', function () {
    it('should create a new student record', function (done) {
            var input = {
                nameLength: 10,
                subjectsLength: 5,
                course: 'CAS'
        };
        studentName = student.getRandomName(input.nameLength);
        studentCourse = student.getRandomCourse(input.course);
        studentUnits = student.getRandomUnits(input.subjectsLength);
        studentGrades = student.getRandomGrades(input.subjectsLength);
        studentGWA = student.computeGWA(studentUnits, studentGrades,input.subjectsLength);
        var stringUnits = studentUnits.join();
        var stringGrades = studentGrades.join();
        var generatedStudent = {
            'name': studentName,
            'course': studentCourse,
            'units': stringUnits,
            'grades': stringGrades,
            'gwa': studentGWA
        }
        request(url)
            .post('/addStudent')
            .send(generatedStudent)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.body.should.have.keys(['id', 'name', 'course','units', 'grades', 'gwa']);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
    describe('save()', function() {
        console.log(insertedId);
        it('should generate a student record', function(done) {
            request(url)
                .get('/generateStudent')
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    res.should.have.status(200);
                    res.body.should.not.have.property('name', null);
                    res.body.should.not.have.property('course', null);
                    generatedStudent = res.body;
                    done();
                });
        });
        it('should not have duplicate name', function(done) {
            request(url)
                .get('/getStudents')
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    res.body.forEach(function(iteration) {
                        assert.notEqual(iteration, generatedStudent.name);
                    });
                    done();
                });
        });
        it("now adding to the database", function(done) {
            request(url)
                .post('/addStudent')
                .send(generatedStudent)
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    res.body.should.have.status(200);
                    console.log(res.body.id);
                    res.body.should.have.keys(['id', 'name', 'course', 'units', 'grades', 'gwa']);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```

----------SECOND UPDATE after following Zeeshan's code------------------
they keep on rejecting my edit in the comment section.

Again, I've tried your suggestion but still no cigar. I've also printed the "newRow" to show that the data is being retrieved properly, it's just that when I try the res.send function, it is being read as undefined therefore causing the error. Thank you for your patience!

```
Server Connected on port:  1337


  Student Details
    insert()
Database is connected ... nn
If error, I should not be printed
Value of row.insertId  34
{ id: 34,
  name: 'H3tno72Osk',
  course: 'BS Computer Science',
  units: '4,1,2,4,2',
  grades: '3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,4.0',
  gwa: 3 }
      ✓ should create a new student record (66ms)
    save()
      ✓ should generate a student record
      ✓ should not have duplicate name
      1) now adding to the database


  3 passing (90ms)
  1 failing

  1) Student Details save() now adding to the database:
     Uncaught AssertionError: expected Object { body: undefined, statusCode: undefined } to have property statusCode of 200 (got undefined)
      at Assertion.fail (node_modules/should/lib/assertion.js:92:17)
      at Assertion.Object.defineProperty.value [as status] (node_modules/should/lib/assertion.js:164:19)
      at Test.<anonymous> (test/studentdb.js:86:27)
      at Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:156:6)
      at assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:127:12)
      at node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:124:5
      at Test.Request.callback (node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:691:12)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:922:12)
      at _stream_readable.js:920:16
```

Comment: Could you log the error: if(err) {console.log(err); res.send('Error in query');}

Comment: If InsertId is undefined, then somewhere it's not being defined. I know that sounds silly, but that's exactly the problem. You should check your query is right, that it is getting the right data, that it is being sent the right data to select data, and that it is being sent back from the server okay. Since you have row.insertId several times, it's difficult for me to say which one is the culprit. Perhaps the console is giving you a line number for us to pinpoint?

Comment: use promises to get proper calls

Comment: @WoodyPayne if i print out row contains the information returned by mysql after doing the query, "contains the affected row, insertId, etc". If i print out row, i can see that everything in there is correct, but when i pass down row to the selectOne function, it tells me that it is undefined and it cannot access insertId.

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury 
this is the log, "Uncaught AssertionError: expected Object { body: undefined, statusCode: undefined } to have property statusCode of 200 (got undefined)"

Comment: @boomcode can you give out an example?

Comment: `res.send(552, {message: 'Student Details ('+row.insertId+') was not created.'});`, can you comment this and give try and let know what do you see?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon thanks for the edit. I tried commenting it, still the same.

Comment: okay great, it means error is due to first occurence, please replace your code with my code in answer and share what you see in following lines?
`console.log("If Errror I should not pe printed");
    console.log("Value of row.insertId ", row.insertId);`

Comment: If you try any other query, does that work? Is the connection is setup properly?

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury yes. you can check out my results below, showing that it passed other queries, except for the one where I return the response and being read as undefined.

Comment: Are you sure .should.have.keys have to have id, ['id', 'name', 'course','units', 'grades', 'gwa'], because when creating you don't have id yet.

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury I can remove that, but the problem is that the whole response is not being treated as a json object, rather an undefined one.

Comment: To reply to **@Zeeshan** You need to edit your question, and post the required content. Please **do not** post an edit to his answer with that content. 3 Users have reviewed and rejected it in the review queue, and the message saying *Please approve this* does not change anything. Do not do this again. Thank you.

Comment: @Druzion i see, sorry.

Comment: @MarkAnthonySulleza No problem, just don't do it again. You may want to read some rules in the [Help]

Comment: Please try declaring selectOne before the save function, or declare it as `function selectOne` instead of `var selectOne = function`.

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have managed to get the result that I wanted. I ended up comparing the id count from the insert() function, instead of the save() function.

describe('insert()', function () {

```
it('should create a new student record', function (done) {
    var input = {
        nameLength: 10,
        subjectsLength: 5,
        course: 'CAS'
    };
    studentName = student.getRandomName(input.nameLength);
    studentCourse = student.getRandomCourse(input.course);
    studentUnits = student.getRandomUnits(input.subjectsLength);
    studentGrades = student.getRandomGrades(input.subjectsLength);
    studentGWA = student.computeGWA(studentUnits, studentGrades, input.subjectsLength);

    var stringUnits = studentUnits.join();
    var stringGrades = studentGrades.join();

    var generatedStudent = {
        'name': studentName,
        'course': studentCourse,
        'units': stringUnits,
        'grades': stringGrades,
        'gwa': studentGWA
    }

    request(url)
        .post('/addStudent')
        .send(generatedStudent)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            res.should.have.status(200);
            insertedId = res.body.id;
            res.body.should.have.keys(['id', 'name', 'course', 'units', 'grades', 'gwa']);
            done();
        });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Modified a bit, Can you try this as well and update with results?

```
exports.save = function(req, res) {

connection.query('INSERT INTO student_details(name, course, units, grades, gwa) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',[req.body.name,req.body.course,req.body.units,req.body.grades,req.body.gwa], function(err, row) {
    if(err) return res.send('Error in query');
    console.log("If Errror I should not pe printed");
    console.log("Value of row.insertId ", row.insertId);
    selectOne(row.insertId, function(newRow, insertId){
        if(err) res.status(554).send('Error in query');
        if(newRow == null){
            res.send(552, {message: 'Student Details ('+insertId+') was not created.'});
        } else{
            res.status(200).send(newRow);
        }
    });
});

}

var selectOne = function(id, callback){

connection.query('SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE id=? LIMIT 1', [id], function(err, rows){
    if(err) return err;
    if(rows.length != 0){
        callback(rows[0], id);
    }else{
        callback(null, id);
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should exec `return` if got err. The simplest way to do this is `if(err) return res.send('Error in query');`.